# Database relationship alias naming phrase

Tags: sql, database, orm, strapi

I am aware of database relations, I was taught similar like this below:

[image]

I am developing an web apps with `strapi` cms, in there I can see some relations those are not named academic like `one to one`, `one to many` etc. vice-versa. Instead they used `has one`, `belongs to many` something like this. Not only strappy, I have also encountered this in some other ORM documentations as well. Which is completely okay, but I am not understanding to relate with the above image.

In stripy also the relational symbols are different than the above image.
For example:

> Has One:
> [image]

> Has and belongs to one
> [image]

> Belongs to many
> [image]

> Has Many
> [image]

> Has and belongs to many
> [image]

> Has many
> [image: has many]

I need to know these phrases to relate, is `one to many` similar to `has many`?, is `one to one` similar to `has one`? etc. Also, what is the benefit of use these phrases rather than `one to one` etc.? Is it a topic in DB systems I may be missed?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of different notations for describing relationships, each with its own vocabulary. There’s a reasonable description of them [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model).

On top of these, individual products may use their own, non-standard, notations

Comment: its confusing for me like `has many` vs `Has and belongs to many` because I need sometimes `Zero or many` or `zero or one` etc. relation what is equivalent here? that what actually I asked and your link did not cover it, it covers what I already know in DB systems relations academically.